# Copy specific items from a list of objects with a list of indexes corresponding to the id of the object

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of indices `List<int>` and I want to copy from a list of objects `List<BikeParts>` to another list only the objects with the id's matching to my list of indices.

My code is suposed to get a list of all BikeParts and return only the parts corresponding to the type of my bike (that's why I used a switch-case). I'm trying to use the `List.Findall()` method but I don't really know how to apply it in my case.

```
string Type = "City";

internal virtual List<BikePart> getBikeParts(List<BikePart> allParts)//NOT FINNISHED YET
{
    List<BikePart> partsByModel = new List<BikePart>();
    List<int> partsIndices = new List<int>() {1,2,15,16,17,17,17,17,18,27,27,28,29,29,31,33,34,40,40,42,52};

    switch (Type)
    {
        case "City":
            partsIndices.AddRange(new List<int>() {5,21,30,35,35,39 });//by default black and 26"
            break;
        case "Explorer":
            partsIndices.AddRange(new List<int>() {5,25,30,37,37,39 });//by default black and 26"
            break;
        case "Adventure":
            partsIndices.AddRange(new List<int>() {11,25,37,37});//by default black and 26"
            break;
        default:
            //error
            break;
    }

    foreach (var idx in partsIndices)
        {
            foreach (var part in allParts)
            {
                if (part.id == idx)
                {
                    partsByModel.Add(part);

                }
            }
        }

    return partsByModel;
}
```

I think the code as it is works but I would like to avoid using for and foreach loops. Is there is any way to reduce and optimize this method?

Comment: Why do you not want to use loops? The first optimizations I see is to reduce unreadability. Why do you call the list "indices" while they're IDs? Why do you AddRange () them to a new list, while assignment would suffice? Why use an unmaintainable list of integers like that anyway?

Comment: @CodeCaster, I prefer 1-2 lines of efficient code than a double loop. Yes I plan to rename my variables so it's more readable. And I want to merge 2 lists (one changing from the type of bike), how do I assign like you said? And the list of integers is because it's from a database in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List.FindAll` only provides the `BikePart` instances to the predicate, so you can't use it to select elements by index (unless the `BikePart`s id property always matches it's index).

If you want to avoid using an explicit loop, you can solve it using Linq like this:

```cs
return partsIndices.Select(index => allParts[index]).ToList();
```

**Edit:** I just re-read your comment and it seems to imply that the `id` property indeed always matches the index.

In that case `List.FindAll` *can* be used like this:

```cs
return allParts.FindAll(part => partsIndices.Contains(part.id));
```

**However** this is less efficient, as it will need to do a linear lookup (the `Contains` call) for every existing part (not just the selected ones).
It will also change the behavior of your existing code because it does not return duplicate entries if `partsIndices` contains the same index multiple times (as is the case with your example).

**Update:** The question edit clarified that the part "indices" are actually meant to represent the ids.

In that case a simple lookup by list index is not going to work.
This is your nested loop arrangement as a Linq expression (renamed `partsIndices` to `partIds`):

```cs
return partIds.Select(id => allParts.First(part => part.id == id)).ToList();
```

An alternative approach would be to first convert your list into a dictionary that maps each part id to the part instance and use that for the lookups.
This conversion would only need to be done once and could be reused for additional part queries.

```cs
Dictionary<int, BikePart> partsById = allParts.ToDictionary(part => part.id);
return partIds.Select(id => partsById[id]).ToList();
```

Comment: Ok thanks,
`return partsIndices.Select(index => allParts[index]).ToList();`doesn't work for me, index is out of range.
And yes I want to have the duplicate in my list.

I edited my code to a double foreach loop because a single loop didn't work :
`
foreach (var idx in partsIndices)
            {
                foreach (var part in allParts)
                {
                    if (part.id == idx)
                    {
                        partsByModel.Add(part);

                    }
                }
            }
`
Can the `List.Select()` method still be used?

Comment: I don't understand why you are complicating things so much. If the original, efficient, single loop worked as intended, why would you change it to the inefficient and more confusing nested loop construct?

Comment: About the `IndexOutOfRangeException`: The first Linq expression is exactly equivalent to the loop logic of your original quesion. So if it crashes, that means your `partsIncides` list contains a number equal to or larger than the total number of parts.

Comment: It didn't work, I had an issue of "index out of range" when I added the duplicates and also I didn't use the part.id in the previous single loop, which didn't really matched with my partsIndices list because there is no id 0 (allParts come from a database in mySQL)

Comment: I see, so `partsIndices` should really be called `partIds` then. In that case the efficient index lookup is not going to work. Please see my edit.